# Story about a mathematics discovery that would allow people to replace computers in missiles

Tags: story-identification

Story about a mathematics discovery that would allow people to replace computers in missiles. The government is interested as people are cheaper than computers.

Comment: When did you read this? Novel or short? Any guesses at publishing date? As a new member of the site, take a look at some other questions to see how much information they provide, you give us very little to go on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looking for title & author - short story - possibly called "Arms Race" - about rediscovery of manual arithmetic](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/27748/looking-for-title-author-short-story-possibly-called-arms-race-about-r)

Comment: Both your recent questions are from an anthology called "Nine Tomorrows" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine_Tomorrows

Comment: The Japanese used humans as the guidance system for their WWII missiles: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yokosuka_MXY7_Ohka

Comment: @Jim2B they also used manned torpedoes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaiten

Comment: probably the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/104167/short-story-people-rediscover-how-to-do-math-and-want-to-put-people-in-bombs (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 9):

This is "[The Feeling of Power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Feeling_of_Power)" by Isaac Asimov

### Humanity has forgotten mathematics

> "This is not something we can leak to the firstcomer. Aub!" There was
>   something imperative about his manner of biting off that one-syllable
>   name, but then he was a great Programmer speaking to a mere
>   technician. "Aub! How much is nine times seven?" Aub hesitated a
>   moment. His pale eyes glimmered with a feeble anxiety. "Sixty-three,"
>   he said. Congressman Brant lifted his eyebrows. "Is that right?"
>   "Check it for yourself, Congressman."

### They decide to put humans into missiles

> The general drove on. "At the present time our chief bottleneck is the
>   fact that missiles are limited in intelligence. The computer
>   controlling them can only be so large, and for that reason they can
>   meet the changing nature of anti-missile defenses in an unsatisfactory
>   way. Few missiles, if any, accomplish their goal, and missile warfare
>   is coming to a dead end, for the enemy, fortunately, as well as for
>   ourselves.
>
> "On the other hand, a missile with a man or two within, controlling
>   flight by graphitics, would be lighter, more mobile, more intelligent.
>   It would give us a lead that might well mean the margin of victory.
>   Besides which, gentlemen, the exigencies of war compel us to remember
>   one thing. A man is much more dispensable than a computer. Manned
>   missiles could be launched in numbers and under circumstances that no
>   good general would care to undertake as far as computer-directed
>   missiles are concerned . . ."

You can read the full version online [here](http://downlode.org/Etext/power.html)

Comment: Previously identified in answer to [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/27748/looking-for-title-author-short-story-possibly-called-arms-race-about-r).

Comment: @user14111 - You're absolutely right. VTC as dupe.