# Asimov story about a man who can do calculations on paper

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, mathematics

I'm trying to find a short story by Asimov – I don't think it could be anyone else – where a mid-level office worker brings an underling in to see the boss, and asks the underling to demonstrate to the boss that he can actually add numbers by making marks on paper. More astoundingly, the underling has figured out how to subtract, multiply and (shocker!) even divide.

Comment: The Feeling of Power has been IDed at least six times. See for example [Short story: people rediscover how to do math and want to put people in bombs](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/104167/short-story-people-rediscover-how-to-do-math-and-want-to-put-people-in-bombs).

Comment: typing your exact question title into google lists "The Feeling of Power"

Comment: "Does it always work?"

Answer (score 45):

Isaac Asimov, as you surmised. "[The Feeling of Power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Feeling_of_Power)".

> In the distant future, humans live in a computer-aided society and have forgotten the fundamentals of mathematics, including even the rudimentary skill of counting.

And

> Myron Aub, a low grade Technician, discovers how to reverse-engineer the principles of pencil-and-paper arithmetic by studying the workings of ancient computers

The rest of the story is pretty much as you described. It can be read online [here](https://urbigenous.net/library/power.html).

Comment: This seems to be a popular story: [ISFDB](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41408) but it makes absolutely no sense. If those people can recognize what a computer is, they can do symbol manipulation on paper...

Comment: i remember the story somewhat -- i think they see the possibilities of humans helping to guide spacecraft or something.

Comment: @releseabe - Kind of; human-guided missiles... Humans are cheaper and more expendable than the (at the time) big, heavy, expensive computers needed to control the flight.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer how much long division do you do on paper these days? I can't remember the last time I did.

Comment: @OrganicMarble It's a really simple operation compared to formalizing a question to be posed to a computer. Like someone pretending they can't do dishes because they have used the dishwasher the last 10 years. Anyway, the next step is doing logarithms by hand. Then satisfying equations in boolean logic with about 10000 variables.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer And yet I know plenty of people who have no idea how to _properly_ wash dishes by hand because they’ve never had to learn to do it. And, of course, there’s plenty of early SF that makes absolutely zero sense even if you take it as soft fantasy with a futuristic twist.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer I'm certain I couldn't wash clothes properly without a washing machine. I've seen images of people using washboards....

Comment: This is also reminiscent of the movie [Ideocracy](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0387808/)

Comment: @Barmar did you intentionally misspell that?

Comment: @StevenPenny No, I'm an ideot. :)

Comment: The story dates from 1958. You couldn't get any known computer inside any rocket of that era. According to Wikipedia, "The story is representative of the genre of sci-fi that started in the 1950s as a reaction to computers, around the theme of caution against human mental atrophy in the computer era". News to me.

Comment: @JeremyBoden I mean, given that in that time period they were still using the word "computer" to refer to *people* who did calculations on paper, you certainly could fit one of those in a rocket...

Comment: I dispute this! See a paper written in 1937 "On Computable Numbers, with an Application to the Entscheidungsproblem" by a certain A. M. Turing at https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/plms/s2-42.1.230